# Django best practise for exactly two Child objects "OneToTwo-Relationship"

Tags: python, django, django-models

I want to have a User and a Deal Model.
A Deal has exactly two Users, not more or less.
What ist the best way to achieve this?

I found two ways.

---

**Example 1: Deal.users as ManyToManyField**

```py
class Deal(models.Model):
    users = models.ManyToManyField(AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Pro:

- Logically correct because each user is equal

Contra:

- Needs either ModelForm or a receiver function to validate "len(users)==2"

---

**Example 2: Deal.user1 and Deal.user2 each as ForeignKey**

```py
class Deal(models.Model):
    user1 = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user2 = models.ForeignKey(AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Pro:

- Validation at database level
- Easier to work with in many circumstances

Contra:

- Need to add properties or such if i want to access them equally with Deal.users instead of choosing them explicit (Deal.user1, Deal.user2)

---

What would you consider as best practise?

I would be also happy about any further ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be honest I like option 1 more. I really try to avoid dead end code. I know now you say a deal only contains two users but you don't want to find yourself in a position where a deal sometimes contains 3 and then you need to add in an extra field.

At the same time I'm a big fan of the django-friendships package and their Friend object is very similar to your option 2 however, their fields are from_user and to_user. They then create two friend objects when a friend request is accepted one where you are the from_user and one where you are the to_user. With the help of their FriendManager it works out really nicely.